# Регулярные выражения js

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Всем привет, получаю через аякс html код. В нем содержится сообщения. У каждого свой ид, мне нужно вытащить первый ид из вот такого: id="idms_2372" должен получить 2372.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение будет [выглядеть как](http://regex101.com/r/vY5rR5)

```
/id=[^\d]+(\d+)/
```

только зачем? Правильнее будет вместо html передавать json

Comment: Спасибо щас попробую, просто синтаксис js плохо знаю. У меня там просто сообщения подгружаются с дизайном. А как сделать с json я не знаю.

Comment: Вероятно, он не контролирует отправителя данных :)

Comment: Bars, не совсем понятно о чем это вы?